# How can I add image (e.g. North Arrow) in mapfish layout print with geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, mapfish

I want add north arrow in the map printing using in mapfish with geoserver.

Comment: the possible duplicate is a closed question with no answer

Answer (score 1):

in config.yaml enable rotation:

```
 rotation: true
```

copy arrow image to config dir (beside config.yaml) and add element:

```
        - !image
             width: 12
             url: 'file://${configDir}/north_arrow.png'
             rotation: '${rotation}'
```